# Updating internal version of Git on Aptana

Tags: git, upgrade, aptana

I have the following issue. I downloaded and installed the latest version of Aptana yesterday. It comes with a git terminal built in and installed. However, that terminal is running version 1.7.3.1.msysgit.0

I want to upgrade this to the most resent version of git. I am not sure how to do this for aptana, as my research cannot point to a place to start from to do this. I cannot find the documentation I need. Does anyone know how to upgrade the internal git instance that is shipped with Aptana?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Aptana's terminal (for me at least) is using the same version of Git I get in any command line. The path to the file is located in my PATH environmental variable. For me, msysgit is version 1.7.11 and it is located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git`. The PATH points to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd`. I suspect you could install any git you want and just make sure your PATH points to the correct one.

Side question: Does Aptana's terminal work well for you for Git? I get failed screen wipes whenever I come out of editing a commit message and can't use Ctrl + C to leave insert / edit mode or the whole terminal shuts down.

Comment: Aptana's terminal git works okay, I get those fail screens too. I don't have the same file path to my git as you i.e. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git` but I'll check what you said about installing a different version.

Comment: Also I just noticed git is up to 1.8.3, so I think both of our versions are behind.

Comment: Yeah, I figured I was behind. If you get it updated and the terminal works better, please post back - I'd love to use the internal terminal rather than a separate command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do to update `Git` on `Aptana` is installing Git for Windows, fo instance, and go to Aptana's `Preferences/Team/Git` and point Aptana to the system's Git executable.